# When is the constructor called?

Tags: c++, constructor

In which of the following is the constructor of myClass called?

```
1.  myClass class1;
2.  myClass* class1;
3.  myClass* class1 = new myClass;
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Kind of depends on what myClass is.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: let's suppose it's got a constructor, to begin with.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Yes - default constructor, instance created on stack
2. No
3. Yes - default constructor, instance created on heap

Answer (score 6):

1. The statement would instatiate an object on the stack, call c'tor.
2. Defines only a pointer variable on the stack, no constructor is called.
3. The new operator would create an object in free store (usually the heap) and call c'tor.

But this code will not instantiate any object, as it does not compile. ;-) Try this one:

```
myClass class1; 
myClass* class2;
myClass* class3 = new myClass;
```

- class 1 is a local variable (on the stack), constructor called.
- class 2 is a pointer, no constructor called.
- class 3 is a pointer, the constructor is called, when new is executed.

Answer (score 5):

In both #1 and #3 since you are actually making an instance of the object.  In #2 you are merely declaring a pointer that doesn't point to an instance.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3, because in them you create a myClass object.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is called in cases 1 and 3 when a class is instantiated. The other one (2) only declares a pointer.